# Adding a button a layer above a UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, gmsmapview

I currently have a UIView that is linked to  GMSMapView (google maps) however when I try to overlay a button it appears to be there in the storyboard however when I launch the simulator the button is no longer there.  Is there something special I need to do or is there some way I can add the button programmatically?

Comment: Are you using constraint to position button. Check weather its not hidden behind.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with google maps. My problem was when ill used:

```
self.view = mapView // where mapView ist your GMSMapView
```

I was unable to create any subview in front of GMSMapView.

But with:

```
mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

It was not any problem. So just create your Button programmically, and add it AFTER your GMSMapView (or change layer of subview to bring it in front)

Then all SubViews work fine.

Comment: how do you change the layer of a subview?

Comment: For example with: self.view.bringSubviewToFront(labelView)